# Attempting to use Mozilla Bootstrapper to install Fennoc Opensource, but get error

Tags: android, macos, mozilla, bootstrapping

Im trying to download the source for Fennoc, Mozilla's andriod client as a project for fun to learn somthing about Andriod development.

I use this Curl command from mozilla to run the bootstrapper:

```
curl -O https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/default/python/mozboot/bin/bootstrap.py && python bootstrap.py
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
We tried to install the following Android packages:
tools
But it looks like we couldn't install:
tools
Install these Android packages manually and run this bootstrapper again.
```

I've tried downloading Android Studio to manually download all the SDK elements as the Bootstrapper recommends but continue to get this error. The full trace is below any help is appreciated!

```
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 24.3'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23 rc1' which was not installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 163, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "bootstrap.py", line 154, in main
    dasboot.bootstrap()
  File "/var/folders/7f/g8wm58dn1wv1qxr7_j5lwbpm0000gn/T/tmpBXeDHO/mozboot/bootstrap.py", line 134, in bootstrap
    'content. Like --repo, you should not need to set this.')
  File "/var/folders/7f/g8wm58dn1wv1qxr7_j5lwbpm0000gn/T/tmpBXeDHO/mozboot/osx.py", line 192, in install_mobile_android_packages
  File "/var/folders/7f/g8wm58dn1wv1qxr7_j5lwbpm0000gn/T/tmpBXeDHO/mozboot/osx.py", line 352, in ensure_homebrew_mobile_android_packages
  File "/var/folders/7f/g8wm58dn1wv1qxr7_j5lwbpm0000gn/T/tmpBXeDHO/mozboot/android.py", line 212, in ensure_android_packages
Exception: 
We tried to install the following Android packages:
tools
But it looks like we couldn't install:
tools
Install these Android packages manually and run this bootstrapper again.
```

EDIT: 
This is believed to be the relevant portion of the python script:

```
def ensure_environment(repo_url=None, repo_type=None):
"""Ensure we can load the Python modules necessary to perform bootstrap."""

try:
    from mozboot.bootstrap import Bootstrapper
    return Bootstrapper
except ImportError:
    # The first fallback is to assume we are running from a tree checkout
    # and have the files in a sibling directory.
    pardir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)
    include = os.path.normpath(pardir)

    sys.path.append(include)
    try:
        from mozboot.bootstrap import Bootstrapper
        return Bootstrapper
    except ImportError:
        sys.path.pop()

        # The next fallback is to download the files from the source
        # repository.
        files = fetch_files(repo_url, repo_type)

        # Install them into a temporary location. They will be deleted
        # after this script has finished executing.
        global TEMPDIR
        TEMPDIR = tempfile.mkdtemp()

        for relpath in files.keys():
            destpath = os.path.join(TEMPDIR, relpath)
            destdir = os.path.dirname(destpath)

            if not os.path.exists(destdir):
                os.makedirs(destdir)

            with open(destpath, 'wb') as fh:
                fh.write(files[relpath])

        # This should always work.
        sys.path.append(TEMPDIR)
        from mozboot.bootstrap import Bootstrapper
        return Bootstrapper
```

Comment: How does `bootstrap.py` check for SDK tools' install

Comment: Added the code in the main question where I believe it happens

Comment: I know from the SDK manager that it has the correct platform tools it wants installed so it must be how the script is checking.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, out of thought I attempted the installation as root and it still failed just the same. @Dan wanted to mention that I think the relevant code is found here https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/python/mozboot/mozboot/android.py#188

Comment: more specific this is where the error is raised https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/python/mozboot/mozboot/android.py#212

Comment: @CrandellWS does Mozilla have some where that a possible issue can be posted? Where could we go for the next step up with this issue?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious I am using Ubuntu as opposed to osx and seeing the same basic error... any how there is a guide to to setup without the script...

Comment: can you link to this guide?

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious This is the relevant guide: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android